# Rails avoid N+1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given the following model relationship.

```
group has_many :members
member has_many :missions
mission has_one :game_set_mission
mission has_one :game_set, :through => :game_set_mission
```

Here is what I do

Given group is a Group object

```
# Add a new relationship in member.rb
has_many :game_sets, :through => :missions

# Get all game_set id
group.members.map{ |gc| gc.game_sets.pluck(:id) }
```

But it seems to occur `N+1 query`.

How do I improve my code?

Comment: When you query for group, you could eagerly bring the indirect association: 

`Group.find_by_id(id, :include => [{:member => :mission}])`

Comment: It threw error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: Group.includes(member => :mission)..where(:id => id)

Answer (score 0):

Hope following one help you.

```
GameSet.includes(member: :group)
       .where('groups.id = ?', group.id)
       .pluck('game_sets.id')
```

Comment: I thought instance variable can't use `includes`

Comment: @CodaChang yes you are right, I assume `group` is `Active Relational` object

Comment: Hashrockets are deprecated, please use `member: :group` instead.

Comment: An instance variable can hold any value - a class, a AR relation etc. What you cant do is call scope methods (includes, where...)  if you already have loaded the relation from the DB - which is what happens when you call `.map` or `.pluck` for example.

Comment: you can also write this as `.where(group: group)` which is better since it will use group as a subselect if it it has not been loaded instead of forcing it to load upfront.